# How can I insert a word in a sentence of a PDF content in Java?

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox

I want to add a word in a sentence of a PDF content.

For example:

```
This is a sample content.
```

I want to insert a word in that content like this output.

```
This is a nice sample content.
```

This is a sample code for itextPdf that I found in the internet. Assumed that the content already exists and we want to modify it by adding a text in a sentence.

```
try {
        //Create PdfReader instance.
        PdfReader pdfReader =
                new PdfReader(SRC);

        //Create PdfStamper instance.
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,
                new FileOutputStream(DEST));

        //Create BaseFont instance.
        BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(
                BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN,
                BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

        //Get the number of pages in pdf.
        int pages = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
        System.out.println(pdfStamper.getOverContent(1));
        //Iterate the pdf through pages.
        for(int i=1; i<=pages; i++) {
            //Contain the pdf data.
            PdfContentByte pageContentByte =
                    pdfStamper.getOverContent(i);
            pageContentByte.setFlatness(89);

            pageContentByte.beginText();
            //Set text font and size.
            pageContentByte.setFontAndSize(baseFont, 14);

            pageContentByte.setTextMatrix(50, 720);

            //Write text
            pageContentByte.setWordSpacing(12);
            pageContentByte.showText("hello world");
            pageContentByte.endText();
        }

        //Close the pdfStamper.
        pdfStamper.close();

        System.out.println("PDF modified successfully.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I tried itextPdf and PdfBox but neither of them would work.

I can get the objects in the pdf document using PDFStreamParser of pdfbox.

```
PDFOperator{Td}, COSArray{[COSString{Name }, COSFloat{163.994}, COSString{____________________________________________________}, COSFloat{-8.03223}, COSString{________________________________________________________}]}, PDFOperator{TJ}, COSInt{19}, PDFOperator{TL}, PDFOperator{T*}, COSArray{[COSString{T}, COSInt{36}, COSString{itle}, COSFloat{0.997925}, COSString{ }, COSFloat{-94.9982}, COSString{_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________}]}, PDFOperator{TJ}, PDFOperator{T*}, COSArray{[
```

How can I implement a code that inserts a text?

Comment: How do you suppose to find the text "This is a sample content" in the content stream of a page, knowing that the literal `String` `"This is a sample content"` probably can't be found anywhere in the content stream, even if you can see that text on the page? See my comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844959). You are assuming that PDF is a format that can be used for editing documents. That assumption is wrong! (Did you ever look inside a PDF document? Did you ever examine its internal syntax?)

Comment: You are right @BrunoLowagie, it seems that it isn't possible to edit a complex pdf content. For searching the text "This is a sample content", I planned to use this code(http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs-itext5/replacing-pdf-objects) but I found out that it won't work on most of the pdfs. Thank you.

Comment: @Michael to see how complex PDF is, open some PDF files with PDFBox PDFDebugger or iText RUPS. Btw the answer got upvoted very fast. I've never seen this in many years. So you can bet it is a good one, even if it wasn't the one you had wished.

Comment: *"How can I implement a code that inserts a text?"* - Ok, it looks like you have a very simple PDF ("Name " in one piece, "Title " in only three pieces, all in the order one would expect, an ASCII'ish encoding, probably WinAnsiEncoding with full character set, and form-fill-in-lines drawn using underline characters which one can replace, furthermore whole text lines as **TJ** arguments). If you only need to manipulate that PDF, a solution is feasible. But as mentioned before, these are very fortunate circumstances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not.

Pdf is not a wysiwyg format. Internally, it's more like a file containing code. It has instructions for moving around a cursor, and drawing text and graphics at the tip of the cursor.

Then there's the fact that most instructions get packaged into "objects". All objects get placed in a dictionary that uses byte-offsets to reference them.

So inserting anything in a pdf-document will cause problems on 2 levels.

1. You would mess up the byte-offset of everything in the document
2. You would need to unscramble all the existing rendering operations to make sense of the document (to derive structure like lines of text, paragraph, etc) so that you can properly re-flow the content after you've inserted something.

Hence my short answer. You can't. And that immediately explains why none of the pdf toolkits you've tried can do it. It's simply an insanely hard task.

Comment: Hi @Joris, Thanks for that. Hope we can find a way to solve it and create a plugin to share it to the public. :)

Comment: @Michael Beware, if you find some easy, simple solution somewhere, chances are that it works only for the most primitively built PDFs (Yes, in some PDFs your sentence "This is a sample content." can be found in one piece in a content stream and even is encoded in an ASCII'ish fashion, so you can simply insert an extra word. But such PDFs are more the exception than the rule...)

Comment: @mkl, agreed. :) Thanks

Comment: I can get the objects inside the pdf.

```

Comment: *"I can get the objects inside the pdf."* - That is the trivial part. Retrieving the objects inside and parsing them is easy. And sometimes, see above, you are in luck and find your sentence in one piece. But that is not the general case. The hard part in general is to identify the partial Strings your sentence is split into, making sure the font in question contains glyphs for your addition, and then identifying all fragments one has to move after the insertion (depending on how the following text is drawn, one may or may not have to explicitly move them...).

Comment: @mkl, I agree about the challenging part. I'll get back to you if I created a prototype on this. :)